# Issues Deleting a item in a user Model (array), not sure how to save the result

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a user with various post ID's inside of my mongodb database, I am using mongoose to talk to it.

this is the user object

```
[
    {
        "premium": true,
        "max_posts": 55,
        "posts_made": 52,
        "posts": [
            "5e10046c0be4f92228f6f532",
            "5e1005a9dceb1344241c74c5",
            "5e100753a6cfcb44d8f1fa09",
            "5e1007bea6cfcb44d8f1fa0a",
            "5e1008149324aa1d002a43be",
            "5e1009562826a308a0812e92",
            "5e100a625e6fcb2c90a07bec",
            "5e157143536d6e04a80651bd",
            "5e1e320dc749f23b189ccef7",
            "5e1e3273546d55384c3a975c",
            "5e1e340183d0b0080816cedd",
            "5e1e368bd921f3194c22b3d2",
            "5e1e3732d921f3194c22b3d3",
            "5e1e3a6f9b3017189cff0fe2",
            "5e1e3c1a8c38f11c60354052",
            "5e1e9ab208d0a5416828d0a3"
        ],
        "_id": "5e0fe3f33c2edb2f5824ddf2",
        "email": "user@gmail.com",
        "createdAt": "2020-01-04T01:01:39.840Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-01-15T04:53:08.987Z",
        "__v": 16
    }
]
```

So, I make a request to the database using express, and I try to filter the array, using an id of one post, then I ask express to save that modified user model...

```
router.delete('/testing', (req,res,next) =>{


    userModel.findOne({ email: req.body.author }, function(error, user) {

        user.posts.filter(item => item != req.body.postid)

                user.save((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
            res.json(user)

    });

});
```

my request in postman :

[image]

As you can see, the item is still there in that array... checking the console.log.

Please Advise as I am having doubts, thanks.

Comment: So do you wanted to delete a particular id from `posts` ?

Comment: yes sir , this is what I am trying to do.

Comment: it should work I think but as you can see in the json response, the ID is still remaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You no need to find & update the document of user, which makes two DB calls, plus `.filter()`, try this  :

```
router.delete('/testing', (req, res, next) => {

    userModel.findOneAndUpdate({ email: req.body.author},
        { $pull: { "posts": req.body.postid } }, { new: true }, function (error, user) {
            res.json(user);
        });
});
```

Here we're using `.findOneAndUpdate()` as it returns the updated user document which you need to send back.

Comment: it worked... wow, do you know why my code was not working?? and THANKS ALOT

Comment: @jcx3x : Please print user & check what's going into `.save()`, anyway we don't it anymore :-)

Comment: user was returning as null, but the filter was actually filtering the array , just it would not save the results, well I know the RIGHT was to do it, I will use $pull next time rather than these hacks, thanks!

Comment: @jcx3x : Just saying if it's null then `.findOne()` is not working, print `req.body.author`..

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it using [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator.

The $pull operator removes from an existing array all instances of a value or values that match a specified condition.

```
userModel.update(
    {email: req.body.author},
    { $pull: { posts: { $in: [ req.body.postid ] } } },
    { multi: true }
)
```

For now it seems like you are passing single postid in request body. In future if you needed to delete multiple posts at the same time, you can use the same query by just replacing `{ $in: [ req.body.postid ] }` with `{ $in: [ ...req.body.postid ] }`

Comment: yes this is the same tecnique used by srinivasy , I saw $pull on google , but I assumed it was a mongoDB tecnique and I could not use it in mongoose, im really suprised about this.. and THANKS for the help!